# Apply spring data sort to List or Page object

Tags: spring-data

I'm using Spring Data, I've used a Predicate and a Sort object to retrieve a list of items using the `findAll()` method.

Afterwards, I've made some changes to the resulting object of the query, by adding new elements. Now, how can I reapply the sorting on the modified object while preserving the parameters of the Sort object? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: so you've got back a collection of results, manually added so values to it, and want to apply the same sort that's being done in the database?  This feels grossly inefficient, but once it's in memory your only option is collections sorting where you'll need to recreate the sort logic that's being done by your database engine.

Comment: I agree, I wish I didn't have to deal with sorting and just use the default one. But Spring's Pageable object has sort and I can't rule it out

Comment: Ah, and you're using Paging on top of it, which adds further complexity because you'll have to manually maintain the pages.

Comment: You are right, I have to change my logic